# Groovy Gives call() Error on List Reference

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy's SQL querying functions and MarkupBuilder to write xml files. I have had no trouble doing this in the past, but this time there is a bug that is driving me up a wall. Here is the relevant code:

```
    xml.table() {
    column {
        dataType('string')
        label('Month')
    }
    def numResults = 6

    vals = []
    names = []
    def i = 0
    for(i=0;i<numResults;i++){
        resultset.next()
        vals += resultset.getObject(2)
        names += resultset.getObject(3)
        column {
            dataType('number')
            label(resultset.getObject(3))
        }   
    }
    row {
        month(resultset.getObject(1))
        for(i=0;i<numResults;i++){              
            names[i](vals[i])
        }
    }
```

However when it gets to vals[i] in the second for loop I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.cal
l() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [55]
Possible solutions: wait(long), wait(), any(), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang
.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

FYI the '55' that is referenced here is the first value in the second column, added to the list in this line: `vals += resultset.getObject(2)`

Someone, have any idea what is going on here? I have used list a hundred times just like this with zero trouble. Not to mention that the "names" list functions without a hitch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `resultset` is, `resultset.getObject(3)` is returning a String which you are adding to your list `names` and then you are trying to call this `String` like a function, passing the parameter `42`

Not sure what you're trying to do, and without a working example, it's hard to suggest a fix

Comment: You are right, I was getting way ahead of myself and making big assumptions about the formating in markupBuilder